# Use Jquery to route on laravel route?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, laravel-routing

My anchor link:

```
<td><a href="{!! route('equipments.edit',[$row->id]) !!}">edit</a> / <a href="{!!route('equipmentsDelete',[$row->id])!!}" data-id="{!!$row->id!!}" class="delete-it"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>delete</a>/<a href="{!! route('equipments.show',[$row->id]) !!}">Info</a></td>
```

is produced using for each loop on each row of table for enabling edit,delete ,more info feature on each row.Recently I tried to use bootbox with jquery for confirming before going to delete route.Without using confirmation ,every delete procedure runs smoothly.But when using follwing jquery for confirmation:

```
$(".delete-it").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var del = $(this).attr('href');
    bootbox.confirm(
        "Are you sure?",
        function(result) {
            if(result)
                window.location = del;
        }
    ); 
});
```

It does confirm and then travel to delete route but when returning back to list route after deleting row it says `trying to get property of non-object`.This doesn't happen without using jquery confirmation.How can even this be possible,please someone help??or show some better way to work around with confirmation on delete route on laravel with jquery.

My route:

```
Route::get('/equipmentsDelete/{id}',['uses'=>'EquipmentController@equipmentsDelete','as'=>'equipmentsDelete']);
Route::resource('equipments','EquipmentController');
```

My method equipmentsDelete on controller:

```
public function equipmentsDelete($id)
{   
    Equipment::destroy($id);
    return redirect('equipments')->with('message', 'Deleted!');
}
```

My My index method which shows error only when using jquery:

```
public function index()
{
    $equipments=Equipment::all();       
    return view('equipments.listall',compact('equipments'));

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `del` actually has the correct URL? Is the row getting deleted despite the error?

Comment: yes in 'href' tag of my link I have '{{route("equipmentsDelete,[$row->id]")}}' which generates the URL and is catched by jquery using 'attr()'.I have separate view that only shows deleted rows.When I check that view it gets populated each time I click the delete link.

Comment: I wouldn't just rely on the fact that the `href` value looks correct - use `console.log()` in your javascript code to ensure that you do get the right URL.

Comment: You're going to need to show the code (in the route or the controller) where the error is happening. The error message you're reporting is a PHP error but you haven't shown any PHP code.

Comment: @Kryten just updated the post with more related codes and info...

Comment: Where do you have the `delete` button for a particular resource? Is it in the _listing_  of the resource (i.e. when you get all of those `equipment`s), or in the _show_ action of the resource (i.e when you fetch an equipment to show it to the user)?